# AngularJS : to get response when hitting mail.php using $http

Tags: php, angularjs

This my controller function:

```
$scope.submitContactForm = function() {
    $log.info($scope.contact);
    if ($scope.contactform.$valid) {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://blog.local/php/mail.php',
            data    : $scope.contact, //forms user object
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $log.info(data);
            if (data.errors) {
                // Showing errors.
            } else {
                $scope.messageForm = data.message;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And my mail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
if($_POST) {
if( !isset($_SESSION['sended']) ) {
    // Re-check with php
    if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ):
        $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    else:
      echo $error = 'Name is empty!';
       return;
    endif;

    if( isset( $_POST['contactlastname'] ) && !empty( $_POST['contactlastname'] ) ):
        $lastname = filter_var(trim($_POST['contactlastname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        // Add lastname to name
        $name = ($lastname) ?  $name. ' ' .$lastname : $name;
    endif;

    if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) && !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ):
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if( !filter_var( $email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ):
               echo $error = 'Email is not valid!';
                return;
            endif;
    else:
        echo $error = 'Email is empty!';
      return;
    endif;

   if( isset( $_POST['subject'] ) && !empty( $_POST['subject'] ) ):
        $subject = filter_var(trim($_POST['subject']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    else:
        $subject = "Hello";
    endif;

    if( isset( $_POST['message'] ) && !empty( $_POST['message'] ) ):
         $message = filter_var(trim($_POST['message']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    else:
      echo  $error = 'Message is empty!';
        return;
    endif;

   if(!isset($error)) {
        // if we have no validation errors prepare mail
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

        //Set the hostname of the mail server gmail - yandex- outlook or your hosting's
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // <------------ change with your host name
        // use
        // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
        // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

        //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
        $mail->Port = 465; // <------------ Change with port 25 - 465 - 587 and etc..

        //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // <------------ tls (port 587) or ssl (port 465)

        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
        $mail->Username = "sharjilk62@gmail.com"; // <------------ Smtp authentication - username here

        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = ""; // <------------ Smtp authentication -password here

        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);

        //Set who the message is to be sent to --- CHANGE THIS EMAIL ADDDRES WITH THE ONE YOU WANT TO RECEIVE EMAILS AND WWIT YOUR NAME
        $mail->addAddress('sharjilk62@gmail.com', 'Sharjil'); // <----------- CHANGE YOUR WITH YOUR EMAIL ADDRES

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($message);

        // If send me copy checkbox is checked send a copy to user
        if( isset( $_POST['contactselfemail'] ) ):
            $mail->addCC($email);
        endif;

        // Send mail and report the result
        if($mail->send()):
            echo 'success';
            $_SESSION['sended'] = 'sended';            
        else:
            echo 'error';
            unset( $_SESSION['sended'] );
        endif;
    }
} else {
    echo 'already';
}
}
?>
```

When I am hitting mail.php using $http, it gives me empty string as response and email is not sending to my inbox. I don't know php so much. Can anybody please tell me what changes should be done in mail.php so that the email can sent and to get the proper response of success and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get access to the post-data use this in your php-file:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data_object = json_decode($postdata);
```

After that use

> $var_name = $data_object->var_name;

to get access to the post-data